# In SQL Server, how can I use a statement with mixed types (str and int) correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server 2008 (Management Studio).

I'm trying to update a table on two conditions. These conditions are determined from a column of data with both string and int data.  When I put in this switch statement:

```
update #model_data set tires = case 
    when vehicles = 1 and age = 1 then 2
    when vehicles = 1 and age = 2 then 3
    when vehicles = 1 and age = '3+' then 4
end
```

Note that vehicles can be either 1, 2, or '3+'.  Age can also be 1, 2, or '3+'.I keep getting an error message that says

```
 "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3+' to data type int."
```

I've tried googling around for information about mixed types equality, but I don't really know what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated, as I'm not the most seasoned of SQL users (if you can't already tell...).

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the mixed types in the columns, but I haven't been able to do any combinations of cast and convert statements that seems to correct it.

Comment: Columns do not contain "mixed types'.   Perhaps you are confusing an integer of 1 with a string that has the character '1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this instead:

```
update #model_data set tires = case 
    when vehicles = '1' and age = '1' then 2
    when vehicles = '1' and age = '2' then 3
    when vehicles = '1' and age = '3+' then 4
end
```

That way you are consistently using a character with no implicit need for conversion/casting. I am assuming vehicles and age are both characters.

Comment: yeah, I feel a bit foolish now.  That totally works.  I don't understand why I'm able to do comparisons to the int value in other parts of the script, though.  Is there some default conversion that takes place?

Comment: Yeah, since you are using age=1 and age='3+', the database has to choose whether to do comparisons based on character or integer. In this case it choose comparison based on integer by default. When time came to process 3+, the error showed up.

Comment: Three topics that will help you understand why the SQL works or fails.:
[Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)  
[Data Type Conversion (Database Engine)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx)  
[Constants (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx)